# How to use Cypress.env() inside Cypress/fixtures/sample.js file?

Tags: environment-variables, next.js, cypress, fixtures

I have a `sample.js` file like this:

**Cypress/fixtures/sample.js**

```
module.exports = {
  username: Cypress.env('username'),
  password: Cypress.env('password')
}
```

and **Cypress.json** is like:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
  "video": false,
  "viewportWidth": 375,
  "viewportHeight": 812,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 10000,
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 2,
    "openMode": 0
  },
  "env": {
    "username": "******",
    "password": "******"
  }
}
```

But it doesn't works and returns:

> Cypress is not defined!

Comment: The runner injects Cypress global into tests, but not fixtures. I don't recall seeing a way to import it into sample.js (although maybe with the module api). How are you using sample.js? Is it necessary to dynamically set properties there?

Comment: @MarionMorrison no not necessarily, I removed the fixture file and used the envs in commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call it from fixtures. Cypress.env() are global varibales and can be access everywhere so no need of fixtures.
Simply call it like:

```
    Cypress.env('username'),
    Cypress.env('password')
```

Comment: Actually yes, I did the same. I removed the fixture file and used these envs in commands.

Comment: Please update your answer with more detailed context.